# Shared faces-config.xml across web project

Tags: jsf, faces-config

I am trying to come up with a common UI framework for my organization. I want to know can I have something called shared faces-config.xml file which can be shared across projects.

Answer (score 1):

If you include the faces-config in your JAR, it will be found by any JSF project that you include that JAR within.

Answer (score 0):

Place your `faces-config.xml` in a `META-INF` folder in the jar root.

If you look at component frameworks (richfaces, tomahawk, etc) - they do it this way.